# What does また mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

> また別のときにチェスをしましょう。

The translation was "Let's play chess another time." But what does また change in the sentence? I saw some translations for また, however I couldn't get it.

Comment: Do you mean what does また *do* in the sentence / why would it be natural to use here?

Comment: Both of them, I just don't get what また is doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, "別の時に", "別の機会に", "今度", "次（の時に）", all of these phrases mean "next time, another time."

I guess you are focusing on the use of "また", right?

> When you finish playing chess, you can say
>   "また今度チェスをしましょう。"

---

> When you meet a person who is famous as the best chess player, and you also have strong confidence in playing chess. You want to play chess with him or her, but you have no time to play chess, then you can say,
>   "今度チェスをしましょう" = "Let's play chess another time."

Off course, it's confusing to say "また今度チェスをしましょう" = "Let's again play chess another time."

I'm not sure what you are following, but I hope the above my advise could be helpfull for you. If I misunderstood your question, put your question here again.

また今度ね！

Answer (score 2):

"Let's play chess *again* another time" 
Where また seems to imply that a game of chess was played.